# Error when having a decimal total price

Tags: c#, decimal

the error is in this code. i got the same error a long time ago when i tried to fix this issue regarding the decimals and integers. how can i solve this pls?

```
protected void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productids = string.Empty;
        DataTable dt;
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];

            decimal totalPrice, totalProducts;
            bool totalPriceConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text, out totalPrice), totalProductsConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalProducts.Text, out totalProducts);


            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text,
                CustomerEmailID = txtCustomerEmailID.Text,
                CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text,
                CustomerPhoneNo = txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text,
                TotalProducts = totalProductsConversionResult ? totalProducts : 0,
                TotalPrice = totalPriceConversionResult ? totalPrice : 0,
                ProductList = productids,
                PaymentMethod = rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Text

            };
            DataTable dtResult = k.SaveCustomerDetails();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // loop on how many products are added by the user
            {
                ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()
                {
                    CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]),
                    ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductID"]),
                    TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductQuantity"]),
                };
                SaveProducts.SaveCustomerProducts();
            }

            Session.Clear();
            GetMyCart();

            lblTransactionNo.Text = "Your Transaction Number: " + dtResult.Rows[0][0];

            pnlOrderPlaceSuccessfully.Visible = true;
            pnlCheckOut.Visible = false;
            pnlCategories.Visible = false;
            pnlMyCart.Visible = false;
            pnlEmptyCart.Visible = false;
            pnlProducts.Visible = false;

            SendOrderPlacedAlert(txtCustomerName.Text, txtCustomerEmailID.Text, Convert.ToString(dtResult.Rows[0][0]));

            txtCustomerAddress.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCustomerEmailID.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCustomerName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTotalPrice.Text = "0";
            txtTotalProducts.Text = "0";
        }
    }
```

error is There is no row at position 0. - ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()

Comment: can you provide the error?

Comment: What error are you receiving? A little more info would be appreciated...

Comment: Also note that you're talking about `decimal`, but your code only uses `double` as far as I can tell. `decimal` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes i know sir :( but can you guide me on which specific code will i change or what? pls and thanks. really need this to make it work :)

Comment: error is input string not in correct format.

Comment: I guess Convert.ToInt64(PriceLabel.Text) and Convert.ToInt64(ProductQuantity.Text) are causing error

Comment: Well everywhere you're currently using a `double` you should use a `decimal`. And please edit your question to show the error - along with where it occurred, and what the value was. (I suspect either `PriceLabel.Text` or `ProductQuantity.Text` isn't a valid integer value. Should you be using `Convert.ToDecimal(PriceLabel.Text)` perhaps?)

Comment: @Umriyaev thank you! can you guide me through on how can i overcome the problem? pls and thank you!

Comment: Fundamentally though, you should learn how to diagnose this yourself - find out exactly where the problem is, and most of the code you've posted becomes irrelevant. How far did you get diagnosing the problem before posting the question? (Stack Overflow isn't meant to replace hard work trying to solve things for yourself...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private void UpdateTotalBill()
{
    decimal vat = 0;
    decimal TotalPrice = 0;
    long TotalProducts = 0;
    foreach (DataListItem item in dlCartProducts.Items)
    {
        Label PriceLabel = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label; // get price 
        TextBox ProductQuantity = item.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox; // get quantity

        Int64 priceLabel, productQuantity;
        bool conversionResult = Int64.TryParse(PriceLabel.Text, out priceLabel);
        if(!conversionResult) continue;
        conversionResult = Int64.TryParse(ProductQuantity.Text, out productQuantity);
        if(!conversionResult) continue;
        decimal ProductPrice = priceLabel * productQuantity; //computation fro product price. price * quantity
        vat = (TotalPrice + ProductPrice) * 0.12M; // computation for vat
        vat = Math.Round(vat, 2);
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice;
        TotalProducts = TotalProducts + productQuantity;
    }
    Label1.Text =Convert.ToString(vat);
    txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice + 40.0M + vat); // add vat + 40 delivery charge to total price
    txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
}
```

Int64 structure has TryParse method, which will return false if parsing fails.
Hope this helps.

[Edit]

Try using `TryParse` method when converting `string` argument to number types. It's much more safer. But you should always check the return value before executing further codes. If return value of `TryParse` method was false, you should stop executing the code and inform your user about error.

[Edit 2]

Change this code:

```
ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
{
    CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text,
    CustomerEmailID = txtCustomerEmailID.Text,
    CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text,
    CustomerPhoneNo = txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text,
    TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalProducts.Text),
    TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalPrice.Text),
    ProductList = productids,
    PaymentMethod = rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Text

};
```

to the following code:

```
decimal totalPrice, totalProducts;
bool totalPriceConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text, out totalPrice), totalProductsConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalProducts.Text, out totalProducts);


ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
{
    CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text,
    CustomerEmailID = txtCustomerEmailID.Text,
    CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text,
    CustomerPhoneNo = txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text,
    TotalProducts = totalProductsConversionResult ? totalProducts : 0,
    TotalPrice = totalPriceConversionResult ? totalPrice : 0,
    ProductList = productids,
    PaymentMethod = rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Text

};
```

Comment: thank you sir. im having an error saying operator * cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and double. this is on the vat = (TotalPrice + ProductPrice) * 0.12;

Comment: Try using 0.12M instead of 0.12.   
I edited my code with this values

Comment: yes that removed the error. i tried it again, same error. hmm the error is in the ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart() in my btn_placeorder_click (3rd code from my question) i really want to thank you for helping me out.

Comment: i tried changing the TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalPrice.Text), to TotalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice.Text), but gives me an error "cannot convert decimal to int:

Comment: the program pushes through but the total price results to 0 sir. :(

Comment: Because text in your textbox is not in correct format. Therefore you are getting 0 as a result

Comment: oh okay. but i didnt change anything. computations are still the same. sorry if im being a noob

Comment: should i change the totalpriceconversion result to decimal?

Comment: what are you entering to txtTotalProducts and txtTotalPrice?

Comment: its automatic sir. it is based on the updatetobill function above

Comment: hey that worked fine :) but its rounding off to be a whole number? any trick to get it done as it is? since its a price? the price is 19 778.88 becomes  19 779. this will be my last query for you. you are very kind and informative. please and thanks :)

Comment: The reason I made it was your ShoppingCart class. You made TotalProducts and TotalPrice fields of type int. If you want to write values as they are, then you need to change types of TotalProducts and TotalPrice to decimal in your ShoppingCart class. However, before changing you should check whether your class's logic depends on Int type or not

Comment: yes ive done it and it went through. still rounded off sir.

Comment: got a new error please do check the edited query. i got this a long time ago when i try to fix this issue. regarding decimals pls help :(

Comment: There is no row at position 0. specifically in ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()

Comment: That's why I told you to check your business logic before changing your ShoppingCart! I can't predict what are you doing with your ShoppingCart class. If you don't want to change your business logic just leave my previous edit and change the type of TotalProducts and TotalPrice to int.